# User permission to edit only nodes with taxonomy term

Tags: users

I want to let my customers only edit nodes that have a specific taxonomy term.

For example i have user TimCook from company Apple. He got the role "customer" and i want to give him the right to edit nodes only with the taxonomy term "apple" of the vocabulary "company".

I didn't find any module for this. Maybe there is one, or someone has a hint where i should start to make an own module.

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) module should help you.

> This node_access module governs access to nodes based on the taxonomy
>   terms applied to the nodes. A simple scheme based on taxonomy, roles
>   and users controls which content is visible.

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access)

You may set permission to allow users in role "apple" have the right to view, update or delete nodes with an "apple" term.

Comment: No i have 1000 taxonomy terms / customers so i would have 1000 roles.